# Invalid access to packet even though check made before access

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I get `invalid access to packet` from the eBPF verifier even though I'm performing a check before accessing a byte from a packet. The offset is stored in a `BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY`. The number of loop iterations don't matter because this problem happens even I do one iteration.

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

struct packet_context {
    __u16 pkt_offset;
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") context_table = {
   .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
   .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
   .value_size = sizeof(struct packet_context),
   .max_entries = 1,
};

SEC("xdp")
int collect_ips_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    char *data_end = (char *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    char *data = (char *)(long)ctx->data;
    __u32 index = 0;
    struct packet_context *pkt_ctx = (struct packet_context *) bpf_map_lookup_elem(&context_table, &index);

    if (pkt_ctx == NULL) {
        goto end;
    }

    __u32 length = 0;

    for (__u16 j = 0; j < 253; j++) {
        if (data_end < data + pkt_ctx->pkt_offset + j + 1) {
            goto end;
        }

        if (data[pkt_ctx->pkt_offset + j] == '\r') {
            break;
        }

        length++;
    }

    bpf_printk("%d", length);

end:
    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Here's the error. The error is happening at `if (data[pkt_ctx->pkt_offset + j] == '\r') {` when when j = 0.

```
0: (61) r7 = *(u32 *)(r1 +0)
; char *data_end = (char *)(long)ctx->data_end;
1: (61) r8 = *(u32 *)(r1 +4)
2: (b7) r6 = 0
; __u32 index = 0;
3: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -4) = r6
last_idx 3 first_idx 0
regs=40 stack=0 before 2: (b7) r6 = 0
4: (bf) r2 = r10
; 
5: (07) r2 += -4
; struct packet_context *pkt_ctx = (struct packet_context *) bpf_map_lookup_elem(&context_table, &index);
6: (18) r1 = 0xffff9790029a2e00
8: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
; if (pkt_ctx == NULL) {
9: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+22
 R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2,imm=0) R6_w=invP0 R7_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=0,imm=0) R8_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
10: (69) r1 = *(u16 *)(r0 +0)
 R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2,imm=0) R6_w=invP0 R7_w=pkt(id=0,off=0,r=0,imm=0) R8_w=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; for (__u16 j = 0; j < 253; j++) {
11: (0f) r7 += r1
last_idx 11 first_idx 0
regs=2 stack=0 before 10: (69) r1 = *(u16 *)(r0 +0)
12: (b7) r3 = 253
; if (data_end < data + pkt_ctx->pkt_offset + j + 1) {
13: (bf) r1 = r7
14: (0f) r1 += r6
15: (bf) r2 = r1
16: (07) r2 += 1
; if (data_end < data + pkt_ctx->pkt_offset + j + 1) {
17: (2d) if r2 > r8 goto pc+14
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2,imm=0) R1_w=pkt(id=2,off=0,r=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R2_w=pkt(id=2,off=1,r=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R3=inv253 R6=invP0 R7=pkt(id=2,off=0,r=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R8=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; if (data[pkt_ctx->pkt_offset + j] == '\r') {
18: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r1 +0)
invalid access to packet, off=0 size=1, R1(id=2,off=0,r=0)
R1 offset is outside of the packet
processed 18 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 1 peak_states 1 mark_read 1
```

Even if `pkt_ctx->pkt_offset == 0xffff`, the if condition before the access should prevent accessing a byte beyond the first 0xffff bytes of the packet.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and see if all values in the expression are expected. And if not, start investigating and get some more debugging information and then post that debugging information as well. What you are doing is so pointer-heavy, that it's really hard for humans to solve without having additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR.** You are hitting [a corner-case of the verifier](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.1/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L8435). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70731589/6884590. Adding a bounds check on `pkt_ctx->pkt_offset` will fix it, as noticed by @Qeole.

---

**Verifier Error Explanation**

```
13: (bf) r1 = r7
14: (0f) r1 += r6
15: (bf) r2 = r1
16: (07) r2 += 1
; if (data_end < data + pkt_ctx->pkt_offset + j + 1) {
17: (2d) if r2 > r8 goto pc+14
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=2,imm=0) R1_w=pkt(id=2,off=0,r=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R2_w=pkt(id=2,off=1,r=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R3=inv253 R6=invP0 R7=pkt(    id=2,off=0,r=0,umax_value=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) R8=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; if (data[pkt_ctx->pkt_offset + j] == '\r') {
18: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r1 +0)
invalid access to packet, off=0 size=1, R1(id=2,off=0,r=0)
R1 offset is outside of the packet
```

The verifier is complaining because the packet access (insn. 18) is out-of-bounds. That seems unexpected because you check the packet's length (insn. 17) right before the access.

Unfortunately, the bounds check is not even considered by the verifier because you're hitting [this condition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.1/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L8435). Basically, the maximum value for `R2` is too high (by 1 only for the first iteration) and the verifier thinks there's a risk of overflow.

`R2`'s maximum value is 65535 and its offset is 1 (for the first iteration), so the sum of both is above `MAX_PACKET_OFF` (65535). Considering this is an overflow risk, the verifier returns from  `find_good_pkt_pointers` before it even updates the bounds of all packet pointers.

---

**Solution**

@Qeole is correct that adding a bounds check will help, although not exactly for the reason he states. By adding a bounds check on `pkt_ctx->pkt_offset`, `R2`'s maximum value will be decreased and the verifier will take the packet length check into account.

Comment: Thanks that works. Unfortunately I ran into the same issue again when I reenabled some other code in the same loop. This should help in diagnosing that issue.

Comment: Is this an issue in the verifier? Shouldn't there be some logic that says if a later bounds check is good, override this max value check.

Comment: I think the kernel has to set a limit here to prevent overflows. It can't use the later bound checks because that check might be incorrect if an overflow happened.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that because your offset comes from a map, the verifier cannot use it directly to estimate a boundary (R1's *range*) for accessing the packet.

Try adding a check to bound your offset before your loop:

```c
    if (pkt_ctx->pkt_offset > 1500)
        goto end;

    for (__u16 j = 0; j < 253; j++) {
        ...
```

I tried locally and this seems to work better (the verifier moves on to the next issue, which is that you need to declare the code as GPL-compatible if you want to use `bpf_printk()`).

Comment: Although the fix is correct, the explanation is not exactly true. The same could happen if the offset wasn't coming from a map. It also wouldn't happen if the offset was coming from a map but encoded on less bits of course.