# ebpf: "value is outside of the allowed memory range" when reading data into array with offset

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I'm trying to read data from userspace and store it in a char array. The read may triggered multiple times, so I record an offset when storing the data. I did a bounds check on both the read length and the offset, but verifier still complain that "outside of the allowed memory range".

It seems that after my bound check, verifier believe that both len and offset are in the range of [0,4096). But the conditional statements `event->len + read < MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH` didn't make any sense to verifier and it failed.

below is part of my program

```c
struct ReadArgs{
    int fd;
    uintptr_t buf;  // https://github.com/cilium/ebpf/discussions/1066 work around for pointer in struct
};

struct ReadEvent{
    int eventType;
    int fd;
    int len;
    u8 content[MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH];
};

static __always_inline int readData(struct ReadArgs* args, struct ReadEvent* event, int read){
    if((void *) args->buf == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    event->fd = args->fd;
    if(event->len > MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH){
        return -1;
    } else {
        event->len &= (MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH-1);
    }
    if(read > MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH){
        read = MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH - 1;
    }else{
        read &= (MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH-1);
    }
    if(event->len + read < MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
        long res = bpf_probe_read_user(&event->content[event->len], read, (const void *) args->buf);    // failed at here
        if (res < 0) {
            DEBUG("readData: bpf_probe_read_user return %d", res);
            return -1;
        }
        event->len += read;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the verifier log

```
; if((void *) args->buf == NULL){
109: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r7 +8)        ; R3_w=scalar() R7=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=16,imm=0)
; if((void *) args->buf == NULL){
110: (15) if r3 == 0x0 goto pc+64     ; R3_w=scalar()
; event->fd = args->fd;
111: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r7 +0)        ; R1_w=scalar(umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R7=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=16,imm=0)
; event->fd = args->fd;
112: (63) *(u32 *)(r6 +4) = r1        ; R1_w=scalar(umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6=map_value(off=0,ks=8,vs=4108,imm=0)
; if(event->len > MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH){
113: (61) r2 = *(u32 *)(r6 +8)        ; R2_w=scalar(umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6=map_value(off=0,ks=8,vs=4108,imm=0)
114: (67) r2 <<= 32                   ; R2_w=scalar(smax=9223372032559808512,umax=18446744069414584320,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff00000000),s32_min=0,s32_max=0,u32_max=0)
115: (c7) r2 s>>= 32                  ; R2=scalar(smin=-2147483648,smax=2147483647)
; if(event->len > MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH){
116: (65) if r2 s> 0x1000 goto pc+58          ; R2=scalar(smin=-2147483648,smax=4096)
; int retVal = ctx->ret;
117: (bf) r1 = r8                     ; R1_w=scalar(id=1) R8=scalar(id=1)
118: (67) r1 <<= 32                   ; R1_w=scalar(smax=9223372032559808512,umax=18446744069414584320,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff00000000),s32_min=0,s32_max=0,u32_max=0)
119: (77) r1 >>= 32                   ; R1_w=scalar(umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff))
120: (b7) r7 = 4095                   ; R7_w=4095
; if(read > MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH){
121: (25) if r1 > 0x1000 goto pc+2    ; R1_w=scalar(umax=4096,var_off=(0x0; 0x1fff))
122: (57) r8 &= 4095                  ; R8_w=scalar(umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
123: (bf) r7 = r8                     ; R7=scalar(id=13,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff)) R8=scalar(id=13,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
; event->len &= (MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH-1);
124: (57) r2 &= 4095                  ; R2_w=scalar(umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
125: (63) *(u32 *)(r6 +8) = r2        ; R2_w=scalar(umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff)) R6=map_value(off=0,ks=8,vs=4108,imm=0)
; if(event->len + read < MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
126: (bf) r1 = r2                     ; R1_w=scalar(id=14,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff)) R2_w=scalar(id=14,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
127: (0f) r1 += r7                    ; R1_w=scalar(umax=8190,var_off=(0x0; 0x1fff)) R7=scalar(id=13,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
; if(event->len + read < MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
128: (25) if r1 > 0xfff goto pc+10    ; R1_w=scalar(umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
; long res = bpf_probe_read_user(&event->content[event->len], read, (const void *) args->buf);
129: (bf) r1 = r6                     ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=8,vs=4108,imm=0) R6=map_value(off=0,ks=8,vs=4108,imm=0)
130: (0f) r1 += r2                    ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=8,vs=4108,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff)) R2_w=scalar(id=14,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
131: (07) r1 += 12                    ; R1_w=map_value(off=12,ks=8,vs=4108,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
; long res = bpf_probe_read_user(&event->content[event->len], read, (const void *) args->buf);
132: (bf) r2 = r7                     ; R2_w=scalar(id=13,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff)) R7=scalar(id=13,umax=4095,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
133: (85) call bpf_probe_read_user#112
invalid access to map value, value_size=4108 off=4107 size=4095
R1 max value is outside of the allowed memory range
processed 154 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 12 peak_states 12 mark_read 4
```

I've done some searches on this problem, but can't find a solution.

[Invalid access to packet even though check made before access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873332/invalid-access-to-packet-even-though-check-made-before-access)
[eBPF: invalid access to map value even with bounds check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74178703/ebpf-invalid-access-to-map-value-even-with-bounds-check)
The answers of those question didn't solve my problem.

I guess the root case is the condition `event->len + read < MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH` were not taken into account by verifier. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR.** The verifier is not yet smart enough to use `event->len + read < MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH`.

---

#### Explanation

For the verifier to confirm that `bpf_probe_read_user(&event->content[A], B, ...);` is safe, it would need to remember that `A + B < value_size`. That's what you are trying to guarantee with:

```
if (event->len + read < MAX_READ_CONTENT_LENGTH)
```

Unfortunately, the verifier is currently unable to understand and retain such relations between variables (`A` and `B` or `event->len` and `read` in this example). The only exception is a special case for the pointer to the packet's end (`ctx->data_end`) in case of networking BPF programs.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. So there is no solution to this problem? Maybe I should send the result to userspace every time it read then handle those data in userspace?

Comment: It depends a bit on how you use `readData` I think. What is event pointing to? A map or arbitrary kernel/user memory?

Comment: arbitrary user memory I guess. I'm trying to use this to get the contents of the syscall `read`. That is why it's called mutil times.

Comment: Ok. I was asking because the verifier seems to think it's a map value pointer. Could you share the calling code for `readData`?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood. the event is a structure stored in a hash map and what I want to read using "bpf_probe_read_user" is user memory.

Comment: If the memory region you want to read is in a BPF map, then you don't need to use `bpf_probe_read` to read it. You can simply use `memcpy` (i.e., `__builtin_memcpy`).

Comment: I mean `event` is point to a map value, but the memory I want to read is in user space. That's why I'm using `bpf_probe_read_user`, I don't think memcpy works with it.